# Devops release pipeline azure resource group deployment task with spaces in the template parameter

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-bicep

In a release pipeline I have an Azure Resource Group Deployment task.

I have a bicep file when I am trying to deploy, so The "template" parameter is set to "**\Deploy.bicep".  When it runs, that resolves to ***D:\a\r1\a_POC.ResearchDay.2023-01-26.Azure Web App and DB\drop\Infrastructure\Deploy.bicep***, which has spaces, and this causes the task to fail:

```
2023-02-14T19:34:59.5345426Z ##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
2023-02-14T19:34:59.5366080Z ##[error]Error: Command failed: az bicep build --file D:\a\r1\a\_POC.ResearchDay.2023-01-26.Azure Web App and DB\drop\Infrastructure\Deploy.bicep
ERROR: unrecognized arguments: Web App and DB\drop\Infrastructure\Deploy.bicep
```

I've tried surrounding the template parameter value in single and double quotes, and I get the same error.   I think I could rename my git repo, but I want to know if there is another solution.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be an existing bug https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/16789

Comment: @Oh thanks!  I had two workarounds, Either use the az cli directly to deploy bicep or change the source artifact alias name, which is what I did.